# How to define different response models for different status codes in openApi / springfox-swagger2

Tags: java, swagger, swagger-2.0, openapi, springfox

Given the following REST method with springfox-swagger2 annotations:

```
@GetMapping(value = "/access", produces = MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON_VALUE)
@ApiOperation(value = "check access allowed")
@ApiResponses({
        @ApiResponse(code = 200, message = "okay, there you go", response = AccessResponse.class),
        @ApiResponse(code = 204, message = "I got nothing for you", response = Void.class)
})
public ResponseEntity<AccessResponse> access() {

    if (!isAccessEnabled()) {
        return ResponseEntity.status(HttpStatus.NO_CONTENT).build();
    }
    AccessResponse response = new AccessResponse("some data");
    return ResponseEntity.ok(response);
}
```

Notice that there are two states that this method can return:

1. a response of type AccessResponse
2. a http 204 - no content response

I want to generate a swagger api documentation that reflects the different response models (AccessResponse vs. Void). Inside the @ApiResponse Annotation I explicitly tell springfox-swagger2 to use different models for each state.
Unfortunately the generated swagger api doc json refers only to the AccessResponse model for both http 200 and 204:

```js
"responses":{
  "200":{
    "description":"okay, there you go",
    "schema":{"$ref":"#/definitions/AccessResponse"}
    },
  "204":{
    "description":"I got nothing for you",
    "schema":{"$ref":"#/definitions/AccessResponse"}
    }
}
```

Am I missing something? Is there a way to tell swagger to render two different models for each HTTP/ok status code?

Answer (score 0):

I've changed the return type of the method - removing the generic type:

```
public ResponseEntity access()
```

which results in a better (but not perfect) model description:

```js
"204":{
   "description": "I got nothing for you",
   "schema":{"type":"object"}
}
```

Swagger UI renders this to

[image]

I like that it displays the empty body now. However, the statusCode is a bit irritating.

Comment: Add a wild card `ResponseEntity<?>` and you'll just have an empty set of curly braces